# pentaho CDE : how to link a .prpt file on dashboard?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-ctools

As the title, I am seeking for a solution to link reports(.prpt) made on Pentaho report designer on dashboard.

My reports are in /public/Project.

So I tried with prpt component by setting property like this:

[image]

or like this:

[image]

But in both way, nothing appears.
Also tried with Execute Prpt Component, and same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the prob, just in case someone has the same question: 
On `components panel` - `Execute Prpt Component` - define name, label, Path (/public/Project/list_c.prpt in my example) and html object. If your report has parameters, change `Show parameters` to true.